# Dell Optiplex 9020M can't connect to internet with Ubuntu server 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, server, internet, dell

I am intending to run a server on an old dell optiplex 9020M. But i am having trouble connecting to the internet. It seems like it is not able to detect the internet when going through setup (Ubuntu Server 20.04.3).

I have tried following several guides but to no avail.  I have tried installing the drivers on the following site https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005480/ethernet-products.html but when installing i need packages which can only be obtained through apt-get, which needs internet to work. When i install packages through another computer and transfer via usb i get stuck in a dependency loop where every package needs another package to work.

Do any of you have any idea of what the problem could be? Any help is greatly appreciated. Best regards!

EDIT1:

Based on the comments I have executed the commands requested and here they are:

[Image of the commands and their output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzDzp.jpg)

The commands `sudo netplan generate` and `sudo netplan apply` does not produce any output in the termial.

I have tried to edit the netplan yaml file according to the first answer. This is still my output:

[image: Image of ip addr output]

I have tried the following commands based on answers:
`sudo dmesg | grep eno1` and: `sudo netplan -debug apply`

[image]

Sorry for any inconvenience, this is my first time posting a question.

Comment: Is Ubuntu Server installed on the system? If so, can you [edit] your question to include the output of the following commands: (0) `sudo lshw -c network` (1) `sudo lspci`. With these, it may be possible to identify the issue 

Comment: May we also see: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I have added some more information to the post now!

Comment: Seems perfect so far. What is the exact response to: `sudo netplan generate` and: `sudo netplan apply`

Comment: I added the new information to the post. But neither command produced any output in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, find out the exact name of your netplan file:

```
ls /etc/netplan
```

Next, we will amend the file slightly:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/<what_you_found>.yaml
```

Amend the file to read:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
```

Netplan is very specific about indentation, spacing, etc., so proofread carefully twice. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit the text editor (Ctrl+x).

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Assuming there are no errors or warnings, check to see if you received an IP address:

```
ip addr show
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your answer. I have not gotten an IP after doing these commands. I have added an image of the ip addr command output to the question.

Comment: Please show us: `sudo dmesg | grep eno1` and: `sudo netplan -debug apply` Thanks.

Comment: I have added these informations to the post!